# StaticVariables class and System.Debug statements?

Tags: apex, trigger, debug-logs

I have seen many people writing this kind of `system.debug` :

```
System.Debug('StaticVariables.acccontactTrigger = ' + StaticVariables.acccontactTrigger);
```

What is the use of `StaticVariables` here?  What it do and how it is different from other `debug` statements, such as the one below?

```
system.debug('Resdt:::'+Resdt);
```

Comment: Well, do you have a class named StaticVariables in your org?

Comment: Have you checked if `StaticVariables` class exist in your org?

Comment: MartinLezer &Rohit Mourya Thanks for your answer..Yes StaticVariables is class name.

Answer (score 1):

There's no significant difference between the two. The first happens to reference a static variable in another class, while the second references a static variable, member variable, or local variable in the same class or method. StaticVariables just happens to be the name of a class designed to hold static variables that are shared across classes or triggers, while the second is a variable used locally.